# Any assistance with resolving the EC signature verification failed (ccer -7) on iOS

Tags: ios, security

I'm trying attempting to create signature verification on iOS platform for when the signature and public key are known.  The goal is to create something similar to Android's **Signature** class to where you pass in a key, some bytes from an unsigned entity,  and a known signature, and then call verify() and it will tell you whether or not the signature is valid.
The public key string is known and is base64 encoded. The signature is also known and is base64 encoded. I know the algorithm is EC SHA 256 for encrypting.  When I create the public SecKey it is 65 bytes and starts with 4. I am also 100% sure of the signature, I compare the byte array for the signature on both iOS and Android.  They are the same BUT Android seems to validate the signature.
I'm pasting the code as to what I am doing.  If anyone can point out what I am doing incorrectly, that'd be great.
Thanks

```
private var algorithm: SecKeyAlgorithm = .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256
typealias SecKeyPair = (publicKey: SecKey?, privateKey: SecKey?)

/**
 Generates a public key using the 256 bit Elliptic Curve Signature
 (a 256 bit EC public key is 65 bytes long and starts with an 04.)
 */
func getPublicKey(keyAsBytes: [UInt8]) -> SecKeyPair {
    let keyType = kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom
    let keySize = 256

    let privateKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false as AnyObject,
                                                 kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyAsBytes as AnyObject]

    let publicKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false as AnyObject,
                                                kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: keyAsBytes as AnyObject]

    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [kSecAttrKeyType as String:          keyType,
                                           kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:    keySize as AnyObject,
                                           kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:       publicKeyParams as AnyObject,
                                           kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:      privateKeyParams as AnyObject]

    var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?
    _ = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)
    
    return SecKeyPair(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privateKey)
}

private func verifyRaw(publicKey: SecKey,
                       updatePackage: Data,
                       signature: Data) -> Bool {
    // #define CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH     32
    // Creates an array of unsigned 8 bit integers that contains 32 zeros
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    // CC_SHA256 performs digest calculation and places the result in the caller-supplied buffer for digest (md)
    _ = updatePackage.withUnsafeBytes {
        CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, UInt32(updatePackage.count), &digest)
    }
    let result = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,
                                 .PKCS1SHA256,
                                 digest,
                                 digest.count,
                                 signature.bytes,
                                 signature.bytes.count)
    return result == errSecSuccess
}

private func verify(publicKey: SecKey,
                    updatePackage: CFData,
                    signature: CFData,
                    privateKey: SecKey? = nil) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    var pbError:Unmanaged<CFError>?
    
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    // CC_SHA256 performs digest calculation and places the result in the caller-supplied buffer for digest (md)
    let data = (updatePackage as Data)
    _ = data.withUnsafeBytes {
        CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, UInt32(data.count), &digest)
    }

    let digestAsData = Data(bytes: digest, count: digest.count)
    if SecKeyVerifySignature(publicKey,
                             algorithm,
                             digestAsData as CFData,
                             signature,
                             &pbError) {
        result = true
        
    } else {
        Log.error(message: "[F_MANAGER] Unable to verify signature \(pbError!.takeRetainedValue() as Error)")
    }
    return result
}

private func isSignatureValid(updatePackage: [UInt8], decodedSignatureBytes: [UInt8], publicKey: String) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    // Generate the Public Key key
    if let decodedKey = Data(base64Encoded: publicKey) {
        let keys = getPublicKey(keyAsBytes: decodedKey.bytes)
        if let pKey = keys.publicKey {
            let decodedSignature = Data(decodedSignatureBytes)
            let canVerify = SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(pKey, .verify, algorithm)
            if canVerify {
                let doRaw = false
                
                let updatePackageAsData = Data(updatePackage)
                if doRaw {
                    result = verifyRaw(publicKey: pKey,
                                       updatePackage: updatePackageAsData,
                                       signature: decodedSignature)
                    if !result {
                        let b64EncodedPackageAsData = updatePackageAsData.base64EncodedData()
                        result = verifyRaw(publicKey: pKey,
                                           updatePackage: b64EncodedPackageAsData,
                                           signature: decodedSignature)
                    }
                } else {
                    result = verify(publicKey: pKey,
                                    updatePackage: updatePackageAsData as CFData,
                                    signature: decodedSignature as CFData)
                    if !result {
                        let b64EncodedPackageAsData = updatePackageAsData.base64EncodedData()
                        result = verify(publicKey: pKey,
                                        updatePackage: b64EncodedPackageAsData as CFData,
                                        signature: decodedSignature as CFData)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.error(message: "[F_MANAGER] Algorithm not supported")
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: what's the output? error/logs etc?

Comment: @Woodstock Unable to verify signature Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67808 "EC signature verification failed (ccerr -7)" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=EC signature verification failed (ccerr -7)} (SoftwareUpdateFileHelper.swift:319)

Comment: I've learned something new: It seems that the signature is generated on a SHA256 digest of the bytes.  Still getting the same problems, but I've updated the code:

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question on Apple Developer forum, and there was a person who gave me some good info. He also indicated I could use CryptoKit which I wound up using.
He explained to me that my keys and signature were in the 'der' format.  I had no idea.  He also indicated that I didn't need to use the SecKeyCreateKeys.
I'm posting this solution in case there is someone else out there who is struggling like I was:

```
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
private func verifySignature(data: Data, key: Data, signature: Data) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    do {
        let publicKey = try P384.Signing.PublicKey(derRepresentation: key.bytes)
        let hash = SHA256.hash(data: data)
        
        let signing384 = try P384.Signing.ECDSASignature(derRepresentation: signature)
        if publicKey.isValidSignature(signing384, for: hash) {
            result = true
        }
    } catch {
        Log.error(message: "[F_MANAGER] Exception \(error)")
    }
    return result
}
```